# How to order retrieved Active Records on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to retrieve ordered records from the ddbb and show them on a list. I get the right records but they are not ordered.

There is a column on rewards named "credits"

```
@rewards = Reward.where(:merchant_id => @merchant.id, :order => :credits)


<ul class="list-group">
    <% @rewards.each do |reward| %>
        <li class="list-group-item"><%= reward.name %>
            <span class="badge"><%= reward.credits %></span>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

I have also tried with no success:

```
 @rewards = Reward.where(:merchant_id => @merchant.id).order(credits: :desc)
```

I get something like this:

NAME      Credits
name1  -  20
name2  -  4
name3  -  25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @rewards = Reward.where(:merchant_id => @merchant.id).order('credits desc')
```

You're mixing rails 4 syntax there, which won't work as you're using rails 3

Comment: Looks like it was reverted in Rails 4.0.1. I believe both syntaxes work, worth a try. now http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/11/1/Rails-4-0-1-has-been-released/

Answer (score 0):

We have the following in our code, and it works, different syntax for rails 4

In Rails 3.2.11, Mongoid

```
Account.order_by(created_at: :desc)
or 
Account.order_by('created_at desc')
```

In Rails 4.0.3, Postgres + Activerecord

```
Account.order(created_at: :desc)
also this will work
Account.order('created_at desc')
```

Comment: I've never seen order_by is that based on a gem or is there a class method or something?

Comment: It's based on mongoid

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference, I didn't realize that it wasn't default rails.